# How to transfer an NFT token from a regular (onCurve) account to a PDA one using Solang

Tags: spl-token, nft, solang

Does anyone have an example of how one can transfer an NFT token from a user account to the PDA one using Solang?

The reason is to be able to acquire NFT-s sent by users on a program account (deposit), and then withdraw those NFT-s back to users.

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be similar to build escrow system although you are dealing with FT. In that case, user send token to the regular account(onCurve) which is owned by PDA. When a token is transferred from one account to another account, it requires authority and PDA account & it's seed + bump seed is used for confirming the transaction (on smart contract side).

As PDA account does not have a private key, it can not be used as a signer on the client side when a transfer instruction is generated. On the client side, PDA owned account's private key is used as a signer. Once the instruction is generated and sent, it is handled on the smart contract side where PDA account can be used as an authority for calling the token transfer function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What we were missing essentially was the creation of the associated token account for the PDA. Now as this one is in place, we are able to transfer user NFT token from the user's associated token account to the PDA's token account.